# How to handle Void success case with Result lib (success/failure)

Tags: ios, swift

**Introduction**:

I'm introducing a [Result framework (antitypical)](https://github.com/antitypical/Result) in some points of my app. In example, given this function:

```
func findItem(byId: Int, completion: (Item?,Error?) -> ());

foo.findItem(byId: 1) { item, error in
   guard let item = item else {
       // Error case
       handleError(error!)
       return;
   }
   // Success case
   handleSuccess(item)
}
```

I implement it this way with Result:

```
func findItem(byId: Int, completion: Result<Item,Error>) -> ());

foo.findItem(byId: 1) { result in
   swith result {
      case let success(item):
         // Success case
         handleSuccess(item)
      case let failure(error):
         // Error case
         handleError(error!)
   }
}
```

**Question**
What is the correct way of implementing a result where the success case returns nothing?. Something like:

```
func deleteItem(byId: Int, completion: (Error?) -> ());

foo.deleteItem(byId: 1) { error in
   if let error = error {
       // Error case
       handleError(error)
       return;
   }
   // Success case
   handleSuccess()
}
```

In java I would implement a Result whats the correct way to do this in Swift

Comment: any issue faced here ?

Comment: How to implement the second example using Result

Comment: still not getting your question .

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The best way is exactly what you've done: `Error?` where `nil` indicates success. It's quite clear and simple.

That said, another answer (and one that I've used) is exactly in your question: "How to handle Void success case with Result." The success case passes `Void`, so pass `Void`:

```
Result<Void, Error>
```

"Void" doesn't mean "returns nothing." It's a type in Swift, a type that has exactly one value: the empty tuple `()`. That also happens to be the type:

```
public typealias Void = ()
```

As a matter of convention, we use `Void` to mean the type, and `()` to mean the value. The one thing that's a bit strange about using `Void` this way in a `Result` is the syntax. You wind up with something like:

```
return .success(())
```

The double-parentheses are a little ugly and slightly confusing. So even though this is nicely parallel to other `Result`-using code, I typically just use `Error?` in this case. If I had a lot of it, though, I'd consider creating a new type for it:

```
enum VoidResult {
    case success
    case failure(Error)
}
```

Comment: VoidResult  is a very elegant name =)

Comment: Very good Result extension can improve readability https://forums.swift.org/t/convenience-member-on-result-when-when-success-is-void/36134/10

Answer (score 10):

You can add this extension, to simplify your life.

```
public extension Result where Success == Void {
    
    /// A success, storing a Success value.
    ///
    /// Instead of `.success(())`, now  `.success`
    static var success: Result {
        return .success(())
    }
}


// Now
return .success
```

[Gists](https://gist.github.com/YanSteph/02d738360dfd4ec7cd29453854ef10e0)

Answer (score 1):

I found Rob's answer really interesting and smart. I just want to contribute with a possible working solution to help others:

```
enum VoidResult {
    case success
    case failure(Error)
}

/// Performs a request that expects no data back but its success depends on the result code
/// - Parameters:
///   - urlRequest: Url request with the request config
///   - httpMethodType: HTTP method to be used: GET, POST ...
///   - params: Parameters to be included with the request
///   - headers: Headers to be included with the request
///   - completion: Callback trigered upon completion
func makeRequest(url: URL,
                 httpMethodType: HTTPMethodType,
                 params: [String:Any],
                 headers: [String:String],
                 completion: @escaping (VoidResult) -> Void){
    let alamofireHTTPMethod = httpMethodType.toAlamofireHTTPMethod()
    
    let parameterEncoder: ParameterEncoding
    switch alamofireHTTPMethod {
    case .get:
        parameterEncoder = URLEncoding.default
    case .post:
        parameterEncoder = JSONEncoding.default
    default:
        parameterEncoder = URLEncoding.default
    }
    
    Log.d(message: "Calling: \(url.absoluteString)")
    AF.request(url,
               method: alamofireHTTPMethod,
               parameters: params,
               encoding:parameterEncoder,
               headers: HTTPHeaders(headers)).response { response in
                guard let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode,
                    (200 ..< 300) ~= statusCode else {
                        completion(.failure(NetworkFetcherError.networkError))
                        return
                }
                completion(.success)
                
    }
    
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this

**Note this is example you can change as per your test**

```
typealias resultHandler = (_ responseItems: AnyObject, _ error: Error) -> Void

func deleteItem(byId: Int, completion: resultHandler){
       completion(Items, error) 
 }
```

**Calling**

```
self.deleteItem(byId: 1) { (result, error) in
            if error ==nil{

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm looking for a solution with Result to keep the  success/failure semantic if possible

Comment: i think this is better method to track your result and error with closure.

Comment: I don't understand how this would work, however. You can't evaluate `!error` since `error` is not a `Bool`.

Comment: yeah that was typo mistake

Comment: That still doesn't make sense. `Error` is not optional. It can't be nil. To skip to the next step, I assume you really meant `(AnyObject?, Error?)`, but that's a terrible pattern. It has 4 cases, two of which are illegal. What is your code supposed to do if passed `(nil, nil)`? The whole point of `Result` is to avoid this pattern that exists in Cocoa only because of ObjC history.